# Bbcode "private function linkify" causing site to goes blank

Tags: php, bbcode

When I was using this forum script on subdomain, it works very fine. But when I decided to move it to my main index (public_html) the site went blank.

At first I thought the error was from  .htaccess, but I later discovered that the cause of the blank site is a particular code inside my bbcode.php.

Somebody should help me check what's wrong with this code:

```php
private function linkify($value, $protocols = array('http', 'mail', 'https'), array $attributes = array(), $mode = 'normal')
    {
                // Link attributes
    $attr = '';
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $val) {
    $attr = ' ' . $key . '="' . htmlentities($val) . '"';
    }

    $links = array();

    // Extract existing links and tags
    $value = preg_replace_callback('~(<a .*?>.*?</a>|<.*?>)~i', function ($match) use (&$links) { return '<' . array_push($links, $match[1]) . '>'; }, $value);
     // Extract text links for each protocol
     foreach ((array)$protocols as $protocol) {
        switch ($protocol) {
            case 'http':
            case 'https': 
                $value = preg_replace_callback($mode != 'all' ? '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i' : '~([^\s<]+\.[^\s<]+)(?<![\.,:])~i', function ($match) use ($protocol, &$links, $attr) { if ($match[1]) $protocol = $match[1]; $link = $match[2] ?: $match[3]; return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="' . $protocol . '://' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a>') . '>'; }, $value);
                break;
            case 'mail': 
                $value = preg_replace_callback('~([^\s<]+?@[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+)(?<![\.,:])~', function ($match) use (&$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="mailto:' . $match[1] . '">' . $match[1] . '</a>') . '>'; }, $value);
                break;
            case 'twitter':
                $value = preg_replace_callback('~(?<!\w)[@#](\w++)~', function ($match) use (&$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="https://twitter.com/' . ($match[0][0] == '@' ? '' : 'search/%23') . $match[1] . '">' . $match[0] . '</a>') . '>'; }, $value); 
                break;
            default: $value = preg_replace_callback($mode != 'all' ? '~' . preg_quote($protocol, '~') . '://([^\s<]+?)(?<![\.,:])~i' : '~([^\s<]+)(?<![\.,:])~i', function ($match) use ($protocol, &$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="' . $protocol . '://' . $match[1] . '">' . $match[1] . '</a>') . '>'; }, $value);
            break;
        }
    }

     // Insert all link
     return preg_replace_callback('/<(\d+)>/', function ($match) use (&$links) { return $links[$match[1] - 1]; }, $value);
}
```

I need it to make topic message display

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `private`.

---

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your function—if there was, it would have broken the page that you copied it from as well. That just leaves your declaration:

```
private function linkify($value, $protocols = array('http', 'mail', 'https'), array $attributes = array(), $mode = 'normal')
```

Moreover, you said that adding the function made the page go blank. This is very important because it indicates a *parsing error* because if it was anything else it would have shown everything *up to the first call*.

---

Now, what part of this declaration can create a parsing error in one place but not another?

```
private function linkify($value, $protocols = array('http', 'mail', 'https'), array $attributes = array(), $mode = 'normal')
```

My best guess where your error is would be the `private` in the declaration; in the original file, this was likely in a class body, making it completely legal, while in the main index, it was **not** in a class body, making it an illegally placed keyword.